# Expose Node.js API on docker with Nginx

Tags: php, node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am new to docker and I have a machine running it where im hosting a Laravel website and a Node.js API, im using Nginx to configure the web server but im having trouble to be able to reach my node API from the outside of the machine.

This is my default.conf file:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 index index.php index.html;
 server_name app.mydomain.com;
 root /var/www/html/public;

 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }

 location ~\.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass php:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
 }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

My node.js api dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY ./media-cloud-node/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY ./media-cloud-node .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Im using docker-compose to run all the requested images, here is the nginx and node parts from the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 nginx:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
  ports:
   - 80:80
  volumes:
   - ./src:/var/www/html
  depends_on:
   - php
 (...)
 node:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: node.dockerfile
  volumes:
   - ./media-cloud-node:/usr/src/app
```

The laravel application is working as expected, however the node.js API is responding with a "502 Bad Gateway" when i make a request to it. I cant figure out why this happens:

[image]

Here is the `docker ps` command output:

[image]

If anyone can help would be great, just tell me if you need any extra information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the point of view of the `nginx` container, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are the `nginx` container, not another container or the host.  You need to `proxy_pass http://node:3000`, using the other container's Compose service name as a host name; see also [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  (`docker ps` should write out text output, and future questions should include that text and not an image.)

Comment: I created a boilerplate for `node` `nginx` and `docker`. Perhaps helpful to take a look: https://gitlab.com/datails/nestjs-docker-nginx-boilerplate

Comment: David,s comment already made it work for me, but i'll take a look anyways, thanks!